# a Mapping url is invalid - MalformedURLException

Tags: android, url, mapping, malformedurlexception

I'm having error in my url. It catches the MalformedUrlExcemptio error. The url is in mapping form in api.

```
String endpoint = "http://10.0.0.1/myapp/index.php/api_receiver/register"
URL url;
    try {
        url = new URL(endpoint);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid url: " + endpoint);
    }
```

but if i will use this url. `http://10.0.0.1/myapp2/index.php/api_receiver/register.php` - it is a valid url but i have an error in my api side since it is not matching with the correct mapping.

thanks

Comment: Try accessing the url from the android browser and see if it works. And what exactly is this url ?

Comment: What version of android sdk do you use?

Comment: Hi , thanks for your responses, it was just a mistake in calling the variable that holds the url. I put it in a enum but when i called it in my mainactivity i used .toString instead of getval. just a careless error. :)